# Push data to Sharepoint list via SSIS package in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-2016

I would like some advice on how to push data to a list on Sharepoint Online site via SSIS project on Visual Studio 2015.

I have previously used Sharepoint List adaptor in Visual Studio 2012 but this adaptor is not available for VS 2015. I know there Odata connection but its only for extracting data from a list.

Is there any other connection I can use in SSIS/VS 2015 to push data to a list on Sharepoint via SQL Server 2016 job server?

Your response will be appreciated.

Comment: the adapters are available in VS 2015 just not for SQL-Server 2014 +. The version of SQL is the issue not VS.  I did find that they have a beta version (I haven't tried) which looks like it supports SQL 2014.... http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/downloads/get/1465238  I will be curious for the answer,  I do know there are a couple of commercial solutions out their and ultimately the lists are actually just stored in a sql database......

Comment: Thansk for the response Matt. How did you add the sharepoint adapter in vs 2015 SSIS toolbox?

Comment: I already had it install but when I installed SQL 2012 so when my project is targeted/pointed at sql 2012 the ssis toobox recognizes the adapter.  If pointed at 2014+ the adapter doesn't show.  However as I mentioned it does look like there is a beta version of the adapter that you can install and might support ssis on sql 2014.  Its a function of the targeted SQL version not the Visual Studio version.  VS 2015 lets you target multiple ssis version which older VS versions didn't allow for that.